# LDAP - Server A -> Server B -> LDAP

Tags: php, curl, ldap

So I have a script on Server B that calls:

`ldap_bind`

and successfully logs in. If I execute the file as: `php ldap_test.php` I have successful output and results.

Now, I need to execute this file from the outside (I know there is a security concern around this! No need to remind it). So I'd like to do (from Server A):

`curl https://server.com/ldap_test.php`

Which returns me that ldap_bind was unsuccessful (note, credentials are intentionally hard coded as of now).

I couldn't find any reason why this shouldn't be possible - and I'm quite curious, anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System specific ... `httpd_can_connect_ldap` (seen through `getsebool -a | grep http | grep ldap` for example) is `off` by default in CentOS.

If one wants to enable, they can use `setsebool` to do that.